# Changing Apache Storm Log4j2 syslog appender from UDP to TCP

Tags: tcp, udp, log4j2, apache-storm, syslog

In my Storm topology, I transfer big batches of JSON data through the Kafka spout to ElasticSearch bolt.

The problem is that Log4j2 used by Apache Storm, uses UDP protocol in its config both for `cluster` and for `worker`:

**Log4j2/Worker.xml:**

```
    <Syslog name="syslog" format="RFC5424" charset="UTF-8" host="localhost" port="514"
        protocol="UDP" appName="[${sys:storm.id}:${sys:worker.port}]" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
        facility="LOCAL5" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" exceptionPattern="%rEx{full}"
        messageId="[${sys:user.name}:${sys:logging.sensitivity}]" id="storm" immediateFail="true" 
        immediateFlush="true"/>
```

As a result - I'm receiving the next error during my topology submission:

> ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:localhost:514 for appender syslog
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error
>   flushing stream UDP:localhost:514

Which is because of the message length.

I wonder if it is possible to change the default protocol of the Apache Storm Syslog appender from UDP to TCP?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have much to do with Storm, as Storm just uses whatever settings Log4j2 supports. I'd have a look at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender, in particular the example given there for a TCP syslog appender.

```
<Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="8514"
            protocol="TCP" appName="MyApp" includeMDC="true"
            facility="LOCAL0" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true"
            messageId="Audit" id="App"/>
```